# I'm trying to increase performance on through pandoc Rmarkdown

Tags: yaml, r-markdown, rstudio, pandoc

I'm trying to tweak pandoc parameters to increase memory and conversion speed, but can't get anything. This is the ouput part in the RMarkdown:

```
output:
  word_document: 
    toc: yes
    pandoc_args: ["-RTS", "-M2G"]
    fig_width: 8
  html_document:
    self_contained: no
    keep_md: no
    pandoc_args:
    - "-RTS"
    - "-M2G"
    - "--to=html5"
    toc: yes
    toc_float: yes
    collapsed: no
    smooth_scroll: yes
    theme: cosmo
    number_sections: yes
    cache: yes
    fig_width: 8
    df_print: kable
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
```

I've beeing trying to export to .html and it took hours to render it. Now I'm trying to export it to word but still the same...it works but it takes a lot of time.
I'm trying to tweak pandoc arguments but can't get this done. Here is the message while rendering...

```
/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS Proceso_NETO.knit.md --to docx --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output Proceso_NETO.docx --lua-filter /home/cesarkero/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --table-of-contents --toc-depth 3 --highlight-style tango -RTS -M2G
```

How can I really change those pandoc_args while doing knitr ? There is something else I can change to increase pandoc conversion from .md to .docx or .html ?

Comment: hours you say? how big is your input file? have you tried calling `pandoc` from the commandline directly instead of via rstudio?

Answer (score 0):

Run-time-system arguments need to be wrapped by `+RTS` and `-RTS` ([docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/runtime_control.html)). So, for example

```yaml
output:
  word_document: 
    pandoc_args: ["+RTS", "-M2G", "-RTS"]
```

But a conversion taking that long is likely suffering from problems that are difficult to fix in this way.